# Generate File of a certain size?

Tags: bash, command-line, files

I'd like to generate a file with the name `example.file`. I could use

```
touch example.file
```

but I want the file to be exactly 24MB in size. I already checked the manpage of touch, but there is no parameter like this. Is there an easy way to generate files of a certain size?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/139261/how-to-create-a-file-with-a-given-size-in-linux

Comment: We will all assume you do not care what the content is so filled with zeroes will be fine.

Answer (score 239, accepted):

You can use dd:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=output.dat  bs=24M  count=1
```

or

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=output.dat  bs=1M  count=24
```

or, on Mac,

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=output.dat  bs=1m  count=24
```

Comment: ... or use bs=1M and count=24. Many find it nicer and easier to read.

Comment: Thank you for your observations. I edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: Maybe dont use huge block sizes, my system did not like `bs=1G count=1`

Comment: On the Mac, use 24m (small m), because the Mac doesn't like the big M. `dd if=/dev/zero of=output.dat  bs=24m  count=1`

Comment: On Android (5.1.1, might (not) be version or phone specific) I had to use a lowercase `m` too.

Comment: What is the problem with large block sizes specifically? I had hoped to use a 1G block size for a 1G file.

Comment: Note that this doesn’t create a 24 MB file, but a 24 **MiB** one (=~ 25,2 MB) – for a 24 MB file use `bs=24MB` or `bs=1MB` respectively. I suppose it’s `mb` on a Mac.

Comment: In my case, dd only created a file of 34MB. max. even if I used a bigger value in bs. Using bs=1M count=500 worked well.

Answer (score 71):

Under non-embedded Linux or Cygwin (or any system with GNU coreutils) and FreeBSD:

```
truncate -s 24m example.file
```

This creates a file full of null bytes. If the file already exists and is smaller, it is extended to the requested size with null bytes. If the file already exists and is larger, is is truncated to the requested size.

The null bytes do not consume any disk space, the file is a [sparse file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_file).

On many systems, `head -c 24m </dev/zero >example.file` creates a non-sparse file full of null bytes. If `head` doesn't have a `-c` option on your system (it's common but not in POSIX), you can use `dd bs=1024k count=24 </dev/zero >example.file` instead (this is POSIX-compliant).

Comment: BusyBox [also has it](https://github.com/insane-adding-machines/busybox/blob/8c89e22f488f1363531f0df3b97351d43ec7fc4b/coreutils/truncate.c), so most embedded systems will too :-)

Comment: Note that this doesn’t create a 24 MB file, but a 24 **MiB** one (=~ 25,2 MB) – for a 24 MB file use `-s 24MB` instead.

Comment: @dessert The asker probably wanted 24MiB. Most people don't use the binary prefixes.

Comment: You really think so? It’s exactly the other way around in my experience – still, don’t you agree that on a question about a certain file size an answer should at least mention the difference? Maybe I know the wrong type of people, but they constantly get confused about it and wonder why their 500 GiB of data doesn’t fit on their 500 GB hard drive.

Comment: My intuitition is that this is the fastest alternative, especially as the file size becomes large.

Comment: As "@Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil'" expressed in answer, Created file doesn't consume actual space in storage. But `fallocate` command does it. Another answer https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/381339/235261

Answer (score 56):

If you don't care about the content of the file, this is much faster than using `dd`:

```
fallocate -l 24M filename
```

Obviously, using `dd` for a 24MB file won't take any time on a modern system, but larger files can be noticeably slow.

Comment: Note that this doesn’t create a 24 MB file, but a 24 **MiB** one (=~ 25,2 MB) – for a 24 MB file use `-l 24MB` instead.

Comment: This should be the top answer. Imagine you needed to allocate a 10 GB file, totally unnecessary to fill it with zeros as suggested in the other replies.

Comment: Note that fallocate is not supported on multiple filesystems including ext3

Comment: thx @Azatik1000, seems to not work on zfs. Although it sounds like the best answer :-/

Answer (score 17):

You can use dd:

> dd if=/dev/zero of=outputfile.out bs=1024k count=24

Or in case you happen to be using Solaris

```
mkfile 24m outputfile.out
```

Comment: mkfile seems to be present on macOS too

Comment: You can also pass `-n` to create a sparse file

Comment: Note that this doesn’t create a 24 MB file, but a 24 **MiB** one (=~ 25,2 MB).

Answer (score 4):

refer [other summary](https://ostechnix.com/create-files-certain-size-linux/):

- truncate

  - `truncate -s 24M example.file`
- fallocate

  - `fallocate -l $((24*1024*1024)) example.file`
- head

  - random data

    - `head -c 24MB /dev/urandom > example.file`
  - zero data

    - `head -c 24MB /dev/zero > example.file`
- dd

  - `dd if=/dev/urandom of=example.file bs=24MB count=1`

    - `dd if=/dev/urandom of=example.file bs=4MB count=6`

Answer (score -1):

```
FROM_NODE=N01;
echo; cd $MOUNT_PATH; pwd; ls -la; sleep 1; echo;
WHEN="$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S)";
fallocate -l 10M $MOUNT_PATH/"$FROM_NODE"_"$WHEN".dump
ls -lha; echo;
```

Comment: Doesn't this say 10 megs while the Q asks for 24?

Comment: `fallocate` could be a good answer, but why all the other lines?  Cut your answer down so that it does just what was asked, and nothing more.

Comment: If you prefer sir:

`fallocate -l 10M somefile.dump`